# Return earliest record with a specific criteria MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the earliest record from a data that is similar to this sample:

```
user_id Criteria_1  Criteria_2  Date
1           1           1       1/1/2015
1           0           1       2/1/2015
1           1           0       3/1/2015
2           0           0       1/1/2015
2           0           1       2/1/2015
2           1           0       3/1/2015
```

Desired result:

```
user_id Criteria_1  Criteria_2  Date
1           1           1       1/1/2015
2           0           1       2/1/2015
```

a.) user_id should be unique
b.) should meet either OR both Criteria_1 , Criteria_2
c.) earliest date

Answer (score 1):

This is the most frequently asked question under the `mysql` tag, but hey, it's a slow day...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(user_id INT NOT NULL
,Criterion_1  TINYINT NOT NULL
,Criterion_2  TINYINT NOT NULL
,Date DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,date)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,1,'2015-01-01'),
(1,0,1,'2015-01-02'),
(1,1,0,'2015-01-03'),
(2,0,0,'2015-01-01'),
(2,0,1,'2015-01-02'),
(2,1,0,'2015-01-03');

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| user_id | Criterion_1 | Criterion_2 | Date       |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 |           1 | 2015-01-01 |
|       1 |           0 |           1 | 2015-01-02 |
|       1 |           1 |           0 | 2015-01-03 |
|       2 |           0 |           0 | 2015-01-01 |
|       2 |           0 |           1 | 2015-01-02 |
|       2 |           1 |           0 | 2015-01-03 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+

SELECT user_id
     , MIN(date) min_date 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE 1 IN (Criterion_1,Criterion_2)
 GROUP 
    BY user_id;
+---------+------------+
| user_id | min_date   |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2015-01-01 |
|       2 | 2015-01-02 |
+---------+------------+

SELECT a.* 
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MIN(date) min_date 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE 1 IN (Criterion_1,Criterion_2)
        GROUP 
           BY user_id
     ) b
    ON b.user_id = a.user_id 
   AND b.min_date = a.date;
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| user_id | Criterion_1 | Criterion_2 | Date       |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |           1 |           1 | 2015-01-01 |
|       2 |           0 |           1 | 2015-01-02 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: I was literally about to click "post" on an identical question. Thanks, Boss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT user_id, 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Criteria_1 ORDER BY Date ASC),',',1) AS Crit_1,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Criteria_2 ORDER BY Date ASC),',',1) AS Crit_2,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Date ORDER BY Date ASC),',',1) AS date_unformat,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(Date,'%d/%m/%Y') ORDER BY Date ASC),',',1) AS date_format
 FROM table
 WHERE Criteria_1 =1 OR Criteria_2 =1 
 GROUP BY user_id
 ORDER BY user_id
```

I have added date with two formats. You can use which ever is applicable to your result

Comment: `FROM table_name` is missing in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` type, you can do this

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` AS a
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') = (SELECT MIN(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y')) FROM table AS b WHERE b.user_id = a.user_id AND  (criteria_1 = 1 OR criteria_2 = 1) )
GROUP BY user_id
```